# Monadic Reduce in the State Monad

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

I'm stuck trying to reduce a list inside a state monad using a function returning `State`:

```
def op(t1: T, t2: T): State[S, T] 
val list: State[S, List[T]]
```

I'd like to reduce the list to get a `State[S, T]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to do this operation safely as written (what happens if the list is empty?), but if you have an identity element for `op`, you can use `foldLeftM` from `Foldable`:

```
list.flatMap(_.foldLeftM[({ type L[x] = State[S, x] })#L, T](opId)(op))
```

Alternatively you could write something like this:

```
list.flatMap {
  case h :: t => t.foldLeftM[({ type L[x] = State[S, x] })#L, T](h)(op)
  case Nil => ???
}
```

Unfortunately in both cases the type parameters are necessary (type inference won't work here), so you'd probably want to define a type alias and avoid the type lambda if you were doing much of this kind of thing.

Comment: I guess, one can also use an unsafe variant: `list.flatMap(l => l.tail.foldLeftM(l.head)(op))`

Comment: @Kolmar If you care enough about safety to put up with the state monad that's unlikely to be something you'd choose to do.

Comment: @TravisBrown Works perfectly, thank you very much. I was pretty close to the solution actually but tried to solve the type inference issue using a type alias instead of a type lambda. Compilation failed due to missing Monad evidence for my type alias